# Detect address in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with `dataDetectorTypes` set to `UIDataDetectorTypeAll` (which should include `UIDataDetectorTypeAddress`), but no matter how I write an address in the text view it's never detected as a link.

Should the address be written in some kind of special format for it to work? Phone numbers, urls, emails and calendar events work perfectly.

Comment: Logging the adress of one of your contacts would help. Also , not sure if it's applying , but check if your textView is editable or not. Can't have editable and data detection at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995219/how-to-make-uitextview-detect-links-for-website-mail-and-phone-number check this will help you