# How to make url string hyperlinked

Tags: objective-c

My property has a string value of a website URL. Is there a way to make it hyperlinked so a user can tap it and launch the website?

```
PartnersDetail *hsName = [PartnersDetail alloc]init];
hsName.partnersURL = @"www.websitehere.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
 -

1. [Fancy Label](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/)
2. [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTTAttributedLabel)
3. [three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question is answered here: [How to make UITextView detect links for website, mail and phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995219/how-to-make-uitextview-detect-links-for-website-mail-and-phone-number)

You need to set the detector types on the UITextView or whatever view you're using to render the text.

But to answer your question - string value itself cannot be 'hyperlinked'. Only the particular rendering of that text and that's it is the renderer's responsibility to add this functionality (in iOS it is UITextView etc.)