# iOS 7 UITextView link detection crash in UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I have a custom `UITableView` cell set up in my `UITableView` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"CELL_IDENTIFIER";

    SGCustomCell *cell = (SGCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) cell = [[SGCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    cell = [self customizedCell:cell withPost:[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

I set up the cell like this (specifically setting the `UITextView.text` to `nil` - as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128056/1313939)):

```
descriptionLabel.text = nil;
descriptionLabel.text = post.postDescription;

descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin - 4, currentTitleLabel.frame.origin.y + currentTitleLabel.frame.size.height + 10, self.frame.size.width - topMargin * 3, 100);
[descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
```

The cells are 100% reusable and `UITextView` is inited like this (as you see, nothing special):

```
descriptionLabel = [[UITextView alloc] init];
descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11];
descriptionLabel.editable = NO;
descriptionLabel.scrollEnabled = NO;
descriptionLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, currentTitleLabel.frame.origin.y + currentTitleLabel.frame.size.height + 10, self.frame.size.width - topMargin * 3, 10);
[self addSubview:descriptionLabel];
```

But when the table has around 50 cells and when I **scroll it fast** I get the following crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'
```

Which is absolutely ridiculous - I comment out this line - `descriptionLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;` and the app stops crashing! I've spent hours trying to figure out what the problem was and now I simply get this.

Tested on iOS 7.0.3

Comment: You are sure its not about `[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`??

Comment: Of course it's not! The crash only happens when the data detector types are turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash happens when two cells with data type are being dequeued while
using the same cell identifier.
It seems to be a bug in iOS, but Apple may have good reasons to implement it this way.
(memory wise)

And so the only 100% bullet proof solution is to provide a unique identifier for cells
containing data types.
This doesn't mean you will set a unique identifier to all cells in your table, of course,
as it will eat up too much memory and your table scroll will be really slow.

You can use NSDataDetector to determine if a matched type was found on your text,
and only then save the found object as the cell identifier, like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *row = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSDataDetector *detector = nil;
    if (!detector)
    {
        NSError *error = NULL;
        detector = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:&error];
    }

    NSTextCheckingResult *firstDataType = [detector firstMatchInString:row
                                                               options:0
                                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [row length])];
    NSString *dataTypeIdentifier = @"0";
    if (firstDataType)
    {
        if (firstDataType.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
            dataTypeIdentifier = [(NSURL *)[firstDataType URL] absoluteString];
        else if (firstDataType.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
            dataTypeIdentifier = [firstDataType phoneNumber];
    }

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%@", dataTypeIdentifier];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
...
```

Note: Initializing NSDataDetector *detector as static
rather than initialize it for each cell improves performance.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the great post! I have simply given up this issue because I couldn't find a solution. I will look into your suggestion in detail later, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AmitP did you try setting attributed text instead of just plain text?

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce your crash. 
Implementing the following method within the TableViewCell subclass

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [descriptionLabel setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
}
```

and add following call within `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` before setting the text:

```
[descriptionLabel setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
```

worked for me. Maybe it cancels ongoing drawing inside the textview and is avoiding the crash that way.

edit: Calling `[descriptionLabel setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeNone];` and `[descriptionLabel setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeLink];` just before setting the text also seems to fix the crash

Comment: So the logic here seems to be the same as with the approach of setting `descriptionLabel.text = nil`?

Comment: It doesn't fix or prevent the crash

Comment: @AmitP confirmed, it does not.

Comment: Setting the field to UIDataDetectorTypeNone and then immediately to UIDataDetectorTypeLink before setting the 'text' property worked for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Providing you are using iOS6 or above, you can use an NSDataDetector to make an attributable string and use that as your TextView text. A modified version of the following method is what we are going to be using.  The method takes a string and some already predefined attributes (like font and text color), and will stop after the 100th link. It has some problems multiple phone numbers, though. You need to define your own code for URL escapping the address.  The the NSDataDetector bit was taken from Apple's NSDataDetector reference: https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
__block NSUInteger count = 0;
if (!_dataDetector)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    _dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber | NSTextCheckingTypeLink
                                                    error:&error];
}
[_dataDetector enumerateMatchesInString:string
                                options:0
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
                                 NSRange matchRange = [match range];
                                 if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
                                 {
                                     NSURL *url = [match URL];
                                     if (url)
                                     {
                                         [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:matchRange];
                                     }
                                 }
                                 else if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
                                 {
                                     NSString *phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",[match phoneNumber]];
                                     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber];
                                     if (url)
                                     {
                                         [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:matchRange];
                                     }
                                 }
                                 else if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeAddress)
                                 {
                 //Warning! You must URL escape this!
                                     NSString *address = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];
                 //Warning! You must URL escape this!

                                     NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@",address];
                                     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                                     if (url)
                                     {
                                         [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:url range:matchRange];
                                     }
                                 }
                                 if (++count >= 100) *stop = YES;
                             }];
return attributedString;
```