# ios 8 UITextView UIDataDetectorTypeLink not working

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

I am setting html text to UITextView and set UIDataDetectorTypeLink to DataDetectorTypes but its not working.below is code:`

```
self.dictHelp =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:response];
[self.txtView setValue:[self.dictHelp valueForKey:@"HelpText"] forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
self.txtView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.txtView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];`
```

Text value is "If you need assistance please contact XXXX at customerservice@xxxx.org"
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add value of Helptext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this code, I found in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121367/uitextviews-in-a-uitableview-link-detection-bug-in-ios-7):- It's a work around but it works nice!

```
self.txtView.selectable = NO; // set it to NO clears all possible data detection work so far.
self.txtView.selectable = YES; // set it to YES so that actual links are detected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below way -

```
 self.txtView.text = nil;
 [self.txtView setValue:nil forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
 [self.txtView setValue:[self.dictHelp valueForKey:@"HelpText"] forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```