# Swift ios8 Textview not detecting Url Properly

Tags: swift, ios8, textview

I have create one chat page and using textView for Text and Url.In IOS9 Url showing properly but the URL problem in IOS8 when I scroll to bottom to top then full text look like a text. It's Not showing blue color URL Properly. What should I do ? Please give me a solution . Strange behaviour, code working in IOS9 but not for IOS8 . Here is my code . this code return in tableview > cellForRowAtIndexPath
**Problem** is example my text is "today is nishant going to this web www.google.com" currently this message showing URL correct but when I scroll up to down then full text color is blue and full text look like a URL and clickable (only IOS8).

```
  cell.textView.selectable = true;
  cell.textView.scrollEnabled = false
  cell.textView.text = getMessage
  cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
```

Please give me solution

Comment: where do you set the color to blue?

Comment: I have click on detection Links property true so its automatically showing link as a blue

Comment: This is a bug in iOS 7.0's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121367/uitextviews-in-a-uitableview-link-detection-bug-in-ios-7