# UITextView becomes unselectable when using textstorage with textcontainer in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, nstextstorage, nstextcontainer

I am trying to display `NSAttributedString` to `UITextView`. I have used `NSTextStorage`, `NSLayoutManager` and `NSTextContainer`. But what happens is `UITextView` becomes unselectable. When i try to select , i can't find any selection or copy - paste options.

I have given `textview.selectable=YES`

I have used multiple textviews with same textstorage. Is that the reason for this problem ?? Or do I have to enable anything else ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved that issue myself !!!!

I believe its the problem when we use same storage and different UITextViews ie. splitting content to different textviews. I didnt find any solution for that.

I solved it by omitting storage, container, & layout manager and by implementing the same features by  other way.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was inspired by [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200846/uitextview-cant-be-selectable-with-textcontainer)

```swift
// Inititialize NSTextStorage
let contents = NSAttributedString(string: "Some attributed string")
let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: contents)
textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

// Fill NSTextStorage with content
let pages = 3
let pageSize = view.bounds.size
for _ in 0 ..< pages {
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: pageSize)
    textContainer.widthTracksTextView = true
    textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textContainer)
}

// Get attributed text of the `page` (NSTextContainer)
let pageNumber = 1
let textContainer = layoutManager.textContainers[pageNumber]
let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRange(for: textContainer)
let substring = textStorage.attributedSubstring(from: glyphRange)

// Set attributed string to UITextView
let textView = UITextView()
textView.attributedText = substring

// UITextView is selectable and editable
// It can be wrapped with UIPageViewController
```