# UITextView Calls Previous Number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITextView` which should auto detect phone numbers. The detection works fine, however if the text is changed the link will call the previous number, even though the actual text has changed. What is the problem? Is this another iOS 7 bug (I have experienced quite a few with `UITextView`?

Comment: It appears so. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962742/uitextview-link-detection-in-ios-7/18968687#18968687) out for a workaround.

Comment: are you saving that tex of textviewt?? where and how?

Comment: @mohitpopat What do you mean by saving the text?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `iOS 7`.

What you can try is resetting the text to nil, before setting the new string.

```
_textView.text = nil;
_textView.text = yourText;
```

This will reset the text view and correct phone number detection should work again.

Comment: Still getting the old phone number. Is there any other workaround?