# UITextView calling previous number

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have an iOS application that looks up employees and shows their work number/mobile number. The problem I am having is after looking up one person and then another, when I click on the number of the person I just looked up, it keeps calling the number of the previously searched person.

And before anyone says anything, I have looked at [UITextView link detection in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962742/uitextview-link-detection-in-ios-7)

I have tried setting the textview.text = nil, disabling and enabling selectable, editable and scrollEnabled. Nothing has worked. If anyone could please shed some light on the problem I am having, that would be great. Thank you!

1. Lookup 1st employee, click on phone# and it calls correct number
2. Lookup another employee (2nd employee), shows correct phone#, click on phone# and it calls 1st employee's phone#
3. Lookup another employee (3rd employee), shows correct phone#, click on phone# and it still calls 1st employees phone#.

the UITextView has selectable = true, detection = phone numbers, editable = NO, have tried setting scroll enabled = YES and NO.

iOS Deployment target is 7.0

Code:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Phone;

found = [happyArray valueForKey:@Extension"];
if ([found length]>0) _Phone.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[found stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Your question and your issue is not clear. Are you saying that you display some text that happens to have a phone number in a text view and if you click the phone link, the proper number is called. But if you then update the same text view with different text with a different number, tapping link calls the previous phone number? Show your relevant code.

Comment: Please update your question with the additional details do it is easer to read.

Comment: done, let me know if you need to see more of the code

Comment: Have you set a break point to see that when you select a person its really who you meant to select.

Comment: I'm still waiting on getting access to a repository so I can actually try some break points out, but when I lookup another person and it displays the correct information, doesn't that mean I have selected the correct person?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an iOS bug, like it mentions in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968687/2747889) of SO. Try setting the text view to editable and then unsetting it just after setting the new number.

If that doesnt work, use setText:nil before setting the number again.

Comment: oh yeah... apparently I had the same problem because I have seen that post before.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. I had tried setting and unsetting the editable before, but I tried that as the same time as setting the text to nil along with selectable and scrollable. But setting and unsetting editable just by itself seemed to do the trick.