# iOS swift: textView with links to another view

Tags: ios, swift, textview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to make a TextView with some test like this one:

> Cras et enim ipsum. Nullam rhoncus [euismod nisi](http://test2.com) at convallis.
>   Etiam accumsan libero odio, eget malesuada [ligula bibendum](http://test2.com)
>   venenatis.

where the links bring you to an other ViewController... I think I should use attributed text to accomplish this, but I really can't figure how...

The other solution would be to use buttons surrounded by labels, but it is not elegant...

Helps?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995219/how-to-make-uitextview-detect-links-for-website-mail-and-phone-number

Comment: nop, with the links I''m to trying to access the web... but just to another view

Comment: use `shouldInteractWith` and handle your detection of link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UITextView` delegate method

[textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview)

You can check for URL in this method where you need to sort of deeplink to another viewcontroller. Also, return false from this method for such cases.

If the URLS can also be opened from outside the app, you may want to look at the Deeplink solutions available in iOS for better management and will give your users a deepklink functionality as well.

Comment: and how can I add the link from the uistoryboard?

Comment: @TheMiotz: Links can be added inside attributed string. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-to-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a). But I don't know how it can be done in storyboard/nib.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the active label frame work available i the github, as I use the same for achieving my goal and it is working fine 

https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift

**Example**

```
func setupAgreement() {

        let customType1 = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\\sterms of service\\b") //Looks for "are"
        let customType2 = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\\sprivacy policy\\b") //Looks for "it"
        let customType3 = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\\scookie use\\b") //Looks for "supports"

        userAgreementLabel.enabledTypes.append(customType1)
        userAgreementLabel.enabledTypes.append(customType2)
        userAgreementLabel.enabledTypes.append(customType3)

        userAgreementLabel.customize { (label) in

            label.text = "UserAgreement".localized
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineSpacing = 4
            label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 0 / 255, alpha: 1)

            //Custom types
            label.customColor[customType1] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor
            label.customSelectedColor[customType1] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor
            label.customColor[customType2] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor
            label.customSelectedColor[customType2] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor
            label.customColor[customType3] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor
            label.customSelectedColor[customType3] = Constant.AppColor.blueColor

            label.configureLinkAttribute = { (type, attributes, isSelected) in
                var atts = attributes
                switch type {
                case customType1:
                    atts[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: self.userAgreementLabel.font.fontName, size: 15.0)
                case customType2:
                    atts[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: self.userAgreementLabel.font.fontName, size: 15.0)
                case customType3:
                    atts[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont(name: self.userAgreementLabel.font.fontName, size: 15.0)
                default: ()
                }

                return atts
            }

            label.handleCustomTap(for: customType1, handler: { (value) in
                self.load(cms: .terms)
            })
            label.handleCustomTap(for: customType2, handler: { (value) in
                 self.load(cms: .privacy)
            })
            label.handleCustomTap(for: customType3, handler: { (value) in
                self.load(cms: .cookie)
            })

        }
    }

    //  func navigateToWebView() {
    //      let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constant.StoryBoardIdentifier.webViewController)
    //      self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //      
    //  }
    func load(cms: CMS) -> Void {
        let cmsController: CMSViewController = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .setting).initVC()
        cmsController.cms = cms
        show(cmsController, sender: cmsController.classForCoder)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the URL being pressed and present your view controller

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
{
    if let urlStr = request.url?.absoluteString
    {
        if (urlStr.lowercased().contains("yourURL"))
        {
            //go to your view controller
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```