# Change URL action in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have an editable UITextView, and if user prints text, containing an image link, I want that image to be opened in my second ViewController and not in a Safari web browser (as it is done by default).

How can I do it?

P.S. The UITextView behavior is set to "Selectable" and Data Detectors are set to "Link".

Comment: You should download the image and set your image on your view controller.

Comment: You can have a webView in second view controller and open the url in that.

Comment: please see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640352/ios-swift-textview-with-links-to-another-view

Answer (score 0):

So implement the `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` function, return FALSE, and then pass the URL to your second view controller, which would download and display the linked image.

Answer (score 0):

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
     //... Handle URL action here ... //
    return false
}
```

and don't forget to add `UITextViewDelegate`