# Detecting URLs real-time while a user is typing it in/pasting it in a TextView

Tags: ios, swift

I need to detect if and when a complete URL has been typed, so I can make a request to get some Metadata for the URL.
This should also work when the user pastes in a URL(which might be a majority of the usecases)

Right now, I'm using the below code to check if a given block of text has URLs and to extract URLs from them.

```
extension String {

   func extractUrlsFromString() -> [String] {
    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link
    let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
    var urlStrings = [String]()

    guard let detect = detector else {
        return []
    }
    let matches = detect.matches(in: self, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count))

    for match in matches {
        if let string = match.url?.absoluteString {
            urlStrings.append(string)
        }
    }
    return urlStrings
  }

}
```

This, I call, from the default UITextViewDelegate method

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let urls = textView.text.extractUrlsFromString()
    if !urls.isEmpty, let url = urls.first {
         // Make API Call to get Metadata for the first URL found
    }
}
```

This method seems to be extremely inefficient, in many ways.
A few things I'd want to change/improve

1. I'd like to call the function to extract a URL, only when required( This condition to be if a certain character limit is met or after a user pasted in.. etc)
2. I'd also like to know if there is a better way to detect a URL, and if the current method is too intensive.
3. Handling the case of when the user edits the url, to avoid multiple API Calls for the same URL.

Thanks!

Comment: `UITextField` has support for detecting links (and phonenumbers and so on) built in so you can tick a checkbox in Interface builder and be done with it :). Have a look at this question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995219/how-to-make-uitextview-detect-links-for-website-mail-and-phone-number hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment!
The support has been enabled. I needed a way to know, if and when a user has typed in a URL ( say to share it to others ) so I can get some metadata for it.
Correct me if I'm wrong, the suggestion you've given is to enable the TextView to display a URL so it can be clickable etc..But I needed it to detect and in turn return a URL, to be used from my side.

Comment: No you're right, my suggestion was only targeted at detecting URLs in the `UITextField`. I don't have anything more intelligent to add, sorry. Hope someone else can help you :)

Comment: Since you want to detect complete URLs, maybe you could link your URL detection to only attempt to detect URLs whenever a character that cannot be part of a URL is typed, such as space or comma (?)

Comment: @FJdeBrienne That sounds smart, but that might solve half the problem I believe?
In the case of the user pasting the URL, the request might never go off.
I'd need to have a different strategy for the case when the user pastes a link in and types no other character in..

Comment: @BhargavVasist in the case of a paste, wouldn't the textViewDidChange method suddenly contain more than one character (you compare it to the old value, that you would have stored previously in textViewDidBeginEditing for example). That could be a way you detect a paste, and apply your URL detection.